# Controlling the GND rail

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, ground

Okay so I'm running into trouble with my small setup, and I'm not sure how to go from here.

I've drawn up a very (terrible) schematic of what I currently have wired up:

[image]

So currently, I have 12v being supplied to the step down regulator, which pumps out 5v to my Raspberry Pi (green one). This works great!

Now, I'm wanting to use the EN pin, which is, the ENABLE pin. If this pin is grounded, it seems to disable the regulator (not really, but lower the voltage almost completly)

Now, I've wired up the yellow Raspberry Pi this way, and it seems to disable to regulator. If I remove the blue wire, the regulator goes back on, and the green Raspberry Pi gets power again.

I can't seem to control this GND pin, atleast, not with software. I'm wanting to find another solution to this. I'm thinking a transistor, but I'm not entirely sure how that would work out.

Can anyone help me out?

Also, please tell me if I'm doing something wrong. Are these pins being used this way safe? Is it not going to ruin my Raspberry Pi or regulator?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you control the EN Pin with a GPIO from the yellow raspberry?

Comment: What you are doing is very reasonable. One thing that is not clear is why there are 2 separate grounds going to the step-down regulator - they are probably connected together in the regulator. Why do you think you need to control the ground pin?

Comment: @KevinWhite That was my initial thought to, but if I remove the GND pin that isn't blue on the yellow RPi, it no longer seems to turn off the green RPi when I connect the blue wire...

Comment: @HervéGrabas It needs to be a GND pin. A GPIO pin won't actually do anything.

Comment: I'm not saying remove anything.  I'm saying that you should have ground on both RPi connected together with the ground on the regulator and the DC jack.  What is "5V0B"? I can't see any such signal on the RPi pinout. I think you have that connected wrong.

Comment: Your comment shows that it seems you are not aware that the GND (aka reference of your circuits) needs to be shared between all your circuits: the regulator, the yellow and green  RPIs. Otherwise, no communication or powering is possible between them. In fact in your schematics you connect regulator GND to 5V pin of the RPis that is incorrect.
Second comment: yes a GPIO pin will work because it can be programmed to be GND. I assume that you didn't use a 35$ piece of hardware juste to have it provide you GND to the EN pin, when is was already available on your regulator.